# Django CSP Allow iframe from domain without having to set CSP for everything else

Tags: python, django, iframe, xss, content-security-policy

I need to allow another domain to embed my website in an iframe. I can use Django CSP to achieve this by setting the following, assuming that `example.com` is the domain that will be hosting the iframe of my website.

```
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", 'example.com')
```

I would like Django to operate as it does out of the box, which is without CSP (correct me if I'm wrong). In this case, how could I achieve this with my CSP configuration?

I currently have this, but it doesn't catch everything, and I'm not sure if it's less secure as Django out of the box, or the same.

```
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'", '*')
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", 'example.com')
```

Is this the same as how django operates by default, or have I made my application less secure by configuring it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using:

```
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'", '*')
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", 'example.com')
```

you made your application usecure because a lot of unspecified directives will fallback to `default-src 'self' *`. This means that scripts/styles/iframes/objects/etc are allowed to be loaded from any external sources.

As I understand you use `django-csp` package by Mozilla. It has a [default values](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#policy-settings) for all directives (they are in *italic*).
If you wish to keep default CSP settings for all directives besides `frame-ancestors` one, you can use a [decorator](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorators.html) to change the `CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS` default's settings.

Comment: Since Django does not use CSP by default, is `CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'", '*')` worse than Django without CSP, or the same? If I cannot do this my only choice is to explicitly set frame-src, img-src, font-src, script-src, etc.. as I am loading from a lot of external resources.

Comment: No, CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'", '*') **is not** worse than Django without CSP, because without CSP inline scripts and eval-expressions are allowed additionally. BUT without CSP you do not need to allow another domain to embed your website in an iframe - nothing prohibits those. Therefore your Django have some CSP by default OR you publish `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header (it do the same as `CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS`). Check and remove `X-Frame-Options` header.